# Change color of text when div is transitioning through it

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transitions

I want to implement a navbar element highlight using a div that moves (via transitions) to the selected element when you click on it.

But in addition, it should change the color of the text it passes through.

See this example (the red highlight is currently moving from "First" to "Second Text", coloring the text inside the highlight white):

[image: highlight transition show-case]

I've made a small codepen to showcase a solution I came up with, which utilizes `position: absolute` and `overflow: hidden`.

See here: https://codepen.io/JZ_CodePen/pen/JjMzpye

Is there a simpler / more professional way to implement this?

Comment: If I slow the transition right down I see that the text is actually copied into the orange blob - yes there has to be a better way.

Comment: @AHaworth yes, you have to manage two transition effects there. You have to slow down the transition of the white text as well (the `.highlight-text` class in the CSS).

Answer (score 1):

That is the best way. Using `position: absolute` and `overflow: hidden` is great. You are also using the `onclick` event of `JavaScript`, which makes it even better. One thing you *could* do is change the `text-color` of the text `onclick`, but then that would make the whole thing white instead of partially like you want.

Comment: I feel like this is a very dirty implementation. I basically move the copy of the elements to the opposite of where the highlight is moving to negate the transitioning, but still benefit from the `overflow: hidden`, which makes the effect possible in the first place.

Comment: It's not. AFAIK, it's the best way. It would be great if you could accept my answer :)

Comment: Your reply is lacking a proper explanation of why this is the best way, no examples of different tried solutions and feels random. Like, why is the use of the onclick event "even better"? Thats how you create an event callback in JavaScript. It is not like I am new to this language. I was hoping someone with a deep understanding of CSS and UI would stumble across this thread. Thanks for your input though!